# Padding vs. line-height in styling anchor

Tags: coding-style, anchor, padding, css

are there any rules/advice when to use padding-top/bottom instead of fixed height and vertical centering with line-height in css styling element ?

What is better/more universal solution (from any perspective)?

This

```
a {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

or this

```
a { 
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pavhan/PCGDW/).

Thank you for your experience

Comment: Should the text content flow over multiple lines (maybe only by accident, on a small screen), results will be quite different.

Comment: Solution to what? What is the *problem*?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/9FpqB/1/

Comment: Thank you all for your comment. CBroe - Text content will not flow over multiple lines, it is only two-words max content. Jukka - Actually, there is no problem. I am just wondering, what is the better to use.

Comment: This article explains a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816123/why-cant-you-set-line-height-on-an-anchor-element

Answer (score 1):

When your text limits to only one line I dont think there's much difference in using either of them (padding, line-height). But when the text is more than one line you may forced not to use line-height.

Answer (score -3):

i am not sure about your problem

padding and line height are entirely different

**padding**

The CSS padding properties define the space between the element border and the element content.

**line-height**

The line-height property specifies the line height.