# Why can't you set line-height on an anchor element with a background?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I've only just realised that anchor tags with a background will only inherit their line-height and you can only set it directly by setting the anchor to display: inline-block;

Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/moefinley/3H3y5/

```
ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: don't use units for line-height - just set a value and it will be relative to the font-size (check out the difference if you remove the px)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is root cause :

> **content-area** = in non-replaced elements, the box described by the font-size of each character in the element, strung together; in
>   replaced elements, the intrinsic height of the element plus any
>   margins, borders, or padding
>
> **inline box** = the addition of (half-)leading to the content-area for each element; for non-replaced elements, the height of the inline
>   box of an element will be exactly equal to the value for line-height;
>   for replaced elements, the height of the inline box of an element will
>   be exactly equal to the intrinsic height of the element plus any
>   margins, borders, or padding
>
> **line-box** = the box which bounds the highest and lowest points of the inline boxes which are part of the line

The following behaviors fall out of this description:

1. the background of an inline element is applied to the content-area
   plus any padding
2. margins and borders on replaced elements affect the height of the
   inline box for that element, and by implication the height of the
   line-box for that line

So your line-height for `a` with background works fine only when you mark it as block element using `inline-block`. And with default behavior it will just stretch the line height without stretching background.

Comment: I've read through this twice and I don't get it :) Maybe it's just because it's the end of the day. But your summary made sense! It's the combination of background and line-height. Remove the background and it works.

Comment: Really really thanks for your explanation \o/